# pyinstaller, import multiple errors

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-import

(pyinstaller 4.3, python 3.9.2)

Using pyinstaller, I would like to make an executable with SrvCopy.py script which contains this:

```
sys.path.append (os.path.abspath ("../objetProcess/"))
from Process import Process
...
```

In the script Process.py, there is

```
import json
...
```

Pyinstaller produces an error: it cannot find json.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "SrvCopy.py", line 33, in <module>
     from Process import Process
   File "C: \documents\sism\objectProcess\Process.py", line 19, in <module>
     import json
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'json'
[6920] Failed to execute SrvCopy script
```

The commands I launched are :

```
pyi-makespec --paths=c:/documents/sism/objetBdd --paths=c:/documents/sism/objetProcess --paths=c:/documents/sism/objetFile2dict  ./SrvCopy.py

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --distpath executables ./SrvCopy.py
```

Do someone have an idea ?

Comment: Have you properly installed python or configured venv?

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for answering ! I don't need a venv. I use python 3.9.2

Comment: Could you please do one thing?

Comment: open cmd then type `py`

Comment: then type `import json` just for checking

Comment: PS C:\documents\sism\objetSrvCopy> py
Python 3.9.2 (tags/v3.9.2:1a79785, Feb 19 2021, 13:44:55) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>>

Comment: I use json in my python programs since februar !

Comment: what is your PyInstaller version?

Comment: pyinstaller version is 4.3

Comment: It is strange but try pyinstaller with `pyinstaller --hidden-import json ...`

Answer (score 0):

as you may probably know inside your dist folder there are packages like tkinter.pyc this files are archives responsible for libiraries check if they are actually there if not either find them on web or use spec files to put it there

Comment: With the flag --distpath executables, I ask pyinstaller to generate the .exe in the "executables" folder. In this folder, I don't see any tkinter.pyc ! tkinter is a librairy for building graphical interfaces, isn't it ?

Comment: try adding import tkinter into spec files